# Python append words to a list from file

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm writing a program to read text from a file into a list, split it into a list of words using the split function. And for each word, I need to check it if its already in the list, if not I need to add it to the list using the append function.

The desired output is:

```
['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

My output is :

```
[['But', 'soft', 'what', 'light', 'through', 'yonder', 'window', 'breaks', 'It', 'is', 'the', 'east', 'and', 'Juliet', 'is', 'the', 'sun', 'Arise', 'fair', 'sun', 'and', 'kill', 'the', 'envious', 'moon', 'Who', 'is', 'already', 'sick', 'and', 'pale', 'with', 'grief']]
```

I have been trying to sort it and remove the double square brackets "[[ & ]]" in the begining and end but I'm not able to do so. And fo some reason the sort() function does not seem to work.

Please let me know where I am making a mistake.

```
word_list = []
word_list = [open('romeo.txt').read().split()]
for item in word_list:
    if item in word_list:
        continue
    else:
        word_list.append(item)
word_list.sort()
print word_list
```

Comment: As TerryA says, you need to work with 2 separate lists, but your code is using `word_list` for both the input lists and output list, and you're making a list inside a list with `[open('romeo.txt').read().split()]`. The most efficient way to do this is to use a `set` but I guess you're doing a homework assignment and you have to do it just using lists. You should also learn about using `with` to open files.

Comment: the statement "open('remeo.txt).read().split()" returns a list already so remove the [ ] from the "[`open('remeo.txt).read().split() ]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two separate variables. Also, `str.split()` returns a list so no need to put `[]` around it:

```
word_list = []
word_list2 = open('romeo.txt').read().split()
for item in word_list2:
    if item in word_list:
        continue
    else:
        word_list.append(item)
word_list.sort()
print word_list
```

At the moment you're checking `if item in word_list:`, which will always be true because `item` is from `word_list`. Make `item` iterate from another list.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm new to Python and this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Remove brackets

```
word_list = open('romeo.txt').read().split()
```

Answer (score 0):

Split returns an list, so no need to put square brackets around the `open...split`. To remove duplicates use a set:

```
word_list = sorted(set(open('romeo.txt').read().split()))
print word_list
```

Answer (score 0):

If order doesn't matter, it's a **one liner**

```
uniq_words = set(open('romeo.txt').read().split())
```

If order matters, then

```
uniq_words = []
for word in open('romeo.txt').read().split():
    if word not in uniq_words:
       uniq_words.append(word)
```

If you want to sort, then take the first approach and use `sorted()`.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `open('remeo.txt).read().split()` returns a list already so remove the [ ] from the `[open('remeo.txt).read().split() ]`

if i say

```
word = "Hello\nPeter"
s_word = [word.split()] # print [['Hello', wPeter']]
But
s_word = word.split() # print ['Hello', wPeter']
```